# Validate sailsjs session cookie

Tags: sails.js, session-cookies

I have a sailsjs frontend that receives an http request, and generates a cookie as explained on https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/sessions. The frontend then makes an http request to another service in the backend, call it Foo. This second request includes the cookie.

As an added security measure, that Foo service should (if possible) verify that the session cookie is valid. Per that concepts page, the cookie is of the form `SESSION_ID.SIGNATURE`, and this is indeed the case, per Dev Tools in Chrome. So Foo must hash `SESSION_ID` with the secret used by the frontend (which I know), the same way that sailsjs did in the frontend, and then Foo can check that the result matches `SIGNATURE`.

But I cannot find how the `SIGNATURE` was generated.

Eg I tried `echo -n "$SESSION_ID" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "$SECRET"` but the result is different from `SIGNATURE`. I then tried all other digests supported by openssl install locally but none of them matched `SIGNATURE`.

Answer (score 0):

So actually I found the sailsjs source code at https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/59b96446404adbb5a0f4debaa83031fd8c54a9cc/lib/hooks/session/index.js#L489 which shows that it is function `sign` of `cookie-signature` module which [has the following code](https://github.com/tj/node-cookie-signature/blob/3bb06287758c8067c9fda55c8d4adea3422bd8ed/index.js#L19):

```js
return val + '.' + crypto
    .createHmac('sha256', secret)
    .update(val)
    .digest('base64')
    .replace(/\=+$/, '');
```

which can be translated to bash as

```bash
echo -n "$SESSION_ID" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "$SECRET" -binary | openssl enc -base64 -A
```

or to python as

```py
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

...

hash = hmac.new(secret, session_id, hashlib.sha256).digest()
hash_base64 = base64.b64encode(hash).decode().rstrip('=')
assert hash_base64 == signature
```